# Java Scripting Engine, getting ReferenceError while passing a reference dynamically to a callback

Tags: java, nashorn, jsr223

I'm using JDK8 Nashorn scripting engine. My script registers a callback at a Java class like this:

```
stream.create().input(".env/router-memory-list/router1").management().onChange(function(){
    print("onChange: "+input.current());
});
```

The `input` referenced in the callback function is set from the Java thread before executing the callback and removed after (`ctx.engineScope` is the Binding object of the script):

```
            ctx.engineScope.put("input", input);
            input.current(message).executeCallback();
            ctx.engineScope.remove("input");
```

It usually works fine but I'm occasionally getting this kind of error while executing the callback:

```
<eval>:15 ReferenceError: "input" is not defined
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.error(ECMAErrors.java:57)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.referenceError(ECMAErrors.java:319)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.referenceError(ECMAErrors.java:291)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.Global.__noSuchProperty__(Global.java:1432)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$Recompilation$4$383$\^eval\_.L:13(<eval>:15)
    at jdk.nashorn.javaadapters.java.lang.Runnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.swiftmq.impl.streams.comp.io.ManagementInput.executeCallback(ManagementInput.java:105)
    at com.swiftmq.impl.streams.processor.StreamProcessor.visit(StreamProcessor.java:92)
    at com.swiftmq.impl.streams.processor.po.POMgmtMessage.accept(POMgmtMessage.java:28)
    at com.swiftmq.tools.pipeline.PipelineQueue.process(PipelineQueue.java:35)
    at com.swiftmq.tools.queue.SingleProcessorQueue.dequeue(SingleProcessorQueue.java:135)
    at com.swiftmq.tools.pipeline.PipelineQueue$QueueProcessor.run(PipelineQueue.java:69)
    at com.swiftmq.impl.threadpool.standard.PoolThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I tried to surround the calling code with a `synchronized` in the hope it might be a threading issue but without success. Looking at the stack trace it might be a recompilation issue where objects that were dynamically set at the `Binding` are getting lost. Any ideas?

Edit - here is how I create the Binding for this script:

```
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName((String) entity.getProperty("script-language").getValue());
    if (engine == null)
        throw new Exception("Engine for script-language '" + entity.getProperty("script-language").getValue() + "' not found!");
    ScriptContext newContext = new SimpleScriptContext();
    ctx.engineScope = newContext.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
```